# C++ Read from input file into struct array

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, and one of my lessons is having me read from a file into an an array of structs(is that how I refer to this?).  I am having issues where my code compiles fine, but sits and spins on a blank screen.  I am fairly sure that the issue lies with how I read the file in.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile;
    const int SIZE = 150;
    int count = 0;
    int index[150] = {};
    inputFile.open("lab9input.dat");
    struct Student {
        string name;
        int studentID;
        int credits;
        int gpa;
    } students[SIZE];
    while (count < SIZE && inputFile >> students[count].name >>
                               students[count].studentID >>
                               students[count].credits >> students[count].gpa) {
        count++;
    }
    cout << endl << "The highest GPA student(s) is: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int high = 0, j = 0;
        if (students[i].gpa > high) {
            high = students[i].gpa;
            for (int k = 0; k < 150; k++) {
                index[k] = 0;
            }
            index[j] = i;
        }
        if (students[i].gpa == high) {
            j++;
            index[j] = i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        if (index[i] != 0) {
            cout << students[index[i]].name << " "
                 << students[index[i]].studentID << " "
                 << students[index[i]].credits << " " << setprecision(2)
                 << students[index[i]].gpa;
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, my text file looks like this:

```
Wesley s012980520 30 3.5
Allen s094589012 120 3.29
Jim   s980469026 145 3.85
Luke s098419346 180 3.6
Helen s124598670 60  3.85
Chole s123309870 60 3.0
```

Am I missing something glaringly obvious?  Thank you for the help!

Comment: [Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) Try `while(count < SIZE && inputFile >> students[count].name >> students[count].studentID >> students[count].credits >> students[count].gpa) ++count;`

Comment: You're missing functions. You can't do much in C++ without at least a `main` function.

Comment: You haven't posted any part of your code that would produce any output. What have you written that would lead you to expect anything else to happen?

Comment: I recommend giving [mre] a read and applying what it teaches to your problem. If  making the MRE doesn't help you resolve the problem, post the MRE here.

Comment: The rest of my code is a for loop printing out students[] and a selection sort function, followed by another for loop printing out the sorted students[].

Comment: You want to present a complete program that misbehaves exactly the same way with s little code as possible. That way those of us out here can drop your code into our compilers and run the results to see exactly what you're seeing. Right now I can make guesses at what went wrong (see the link posted by @TedLyngmo) but I can't guarantee that your program reaches that bug or gets unlucky, bypasses the EOF bug, and fails somewhere else.

Comment: Do any of the student names in your input file have a space in them?

Comment: `s012980520` Is not a valid `int` and cannot be read into `students[count].studentID`. Consider using a `std::string` instead of an `int`.

Comment: @user4581301 also, OP should make `gpa` a floating point number.

Comment: You have loops going to `150` but you only have `count` students in the array.

Comment: More modern way to solve the problem: https://wandbox.org/permlink/2p0Lbeax2rmjz1ch

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the problems in your code:

1. Data type of different variables: Your data (say `Wesley s012980520 30 3.5`) is of the format `string string int float`, which clearly does not match with the types in your `struct Students`.

   To fix this, simply change your struct to:

   ```cpp
   struct Student {
       string name;
       string studentID;
       int credits;
       float gpa;
   } students[SIZE];
   ```

   Also, `high` should be `float` (as it stores `gpa`).
2. `high` and `j` become `0` on each iteration. Move `high` above the loop and `j` to init-list of the loop, like this:

   ```cpp
   float high = 0;
   for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < count; i++)
   ```
3. `index[j] = i;` (first-occurrence) assigns index of student with highest `gpa` to `index[j]` but prior to this, `j = 0` (although the `index` array is reset).
4. The second `if` condition (`if (students[i].gpa == high)`) inside the loop assigns the index of student with highest `gpa` to `index[1]`, if the conditional block above it has executed. Make it `else if` to prevent redundancy.

Suggestions:

5. There is a `setprecision(2)`, if you have put it display `3.6` as `3.60` then you need to add `fixed` before that.
6. There is no need to traverse whole `index` array, you simply need to do that  from `0` to `count`.
7. Remove magic number `150` from your code, use the constant you have declared instead.
8. Put an endline (`'\n'`) after printing each `Student` object.
9. Don't use `std::endl` to put simple newline characters. Use it only if you also need to flush the stream.
10. Avoid putting `using namespace std;` at top of your code.
11. Why put `"` when `'` can do the job ;).
12. `ifstream inputFile` and `inputFile.open` can be written in a single line like : `ifstream inputFile("...")`.

---

Corrected Code (*doesn't work if `name` has spaces in it*):

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // <-- (10), remove this yourself

int main() {
  ifstream inputFile("lab9input.dat"); // <-- (12)
  const int SIZE = 150;
  int count = 0;
  int index[SIZE] = {}; // <-- (7)
  struct Student {
    string name;
    string studentID; // <-- (1)
    int credits;
    float gpa; // <-- (1)
  } students[SIZE];
  while (count < SIZE && inputFile >> students[count].name >>
                             students[count].studentID >>
                             students[count].credits >> students[count].gpa)
    count++;
  cout << "The highest GPA student(s) is(are): \n"; // <-- (9)
  float high; // <-- (1), (2)
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < count; i++) { //<-- (2)
    if (students[i].gpa > high) {
      high = students[i].gpa;
      for (int k = 0; k < 150; k++) index[k] = 0;
      j = 0; // <-- (3)
      index[j] = i;
    } else if (students[i].gpa == high) // <-- (4)
      index[++j] = i;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // <--(6)
    if (index[i] != 0)
      cout << students[index[i]].name << ' ' << students[index[i]].studentID
           << ' ' << students[index[i]].credits << ' ' << fixed // <-- (5)
           << setprecision(2) << students[index[i]].gpa << '\n'; // <--(8)
}
```

---

Better code to do the same thing:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student {
  std::string name, studentID;
  int credits;
  float gpa;

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Student &);
  friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Student &);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Student &s) {
  out << s.name << ' ' << s.studentID << ' ' << s.credits << ' ' << s.gpa
      << '\n';
  return out;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Student &s) {
  s.name.clear();
  std::string str;

  while (in >> str && std::none_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit))
    s.name += str + ' ';
  s.name.pop_back();
  s.studentID = str;

  in >> s.credits >> s.gpa;
  return in;
}

int main() {
  std::ifstream is("lab9input.dat");
  std::vector<Student> v(std::istream_iterator<Student>(is), {});

  auto max_gpa = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) {
                   return b.gpa > a.gpa;
                 })->gpa;

  std::cout << "The highest GPA student(s) is(are): \n";
  for (auto &i : v) if (i.gpa == max_gpa) std::cout << i;
}
```